# How to convert VB statement into C#

Tags: c#

I have dificulties to convert this vb code into C#

```
Dim billingElem As XmlElement = _
    CType(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/billing"), XmlElement)
```

converted as

```
XmlElement uinelement =
    (XmlElement)xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("/Users/user/uin");
```

Error is
Cannot implecitly convert XMLNodeList to XmlElement.

Thanks
Kanta

Comment: It seems quite clear to me that the VB version is calling a different method.

Comment: what tool did you use to do the conversion?

Comment: I have not used any conversion tool. I am converting myself. suggest me the conversion tool

Answer (score 5):

Using [VB.Net to C# Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) you get this:

```
XmlElement billingElem = (XmlElement)xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/billing");
```

Answer (score 3):

GetElementsByTagName can return more than one element, so it returns an XMLNodeList.

Change it to SelectSingleNode, which will only return one element and not a list.

Comment: Thank you Eric, SelectSingleNode seems like working. 
 for this statement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why your converted code is calling a different method, but this will do what your original code does:

```
XmlElement billingElem = (XmlElement)xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/billing");
```

Comment: Yeah but I beat you by 2 minutes and explained the answer as well ;-)

Comment: I beat you all by not playing.

Comment: @Jon B: Better to teach how to fish ;-) Neener neener neener.

Comment: Can you suggest me the convertion tool I am getting other exception error. While trying to convert VB to C# myself. Kanta

Comment: @Kanta: Dr.Optix recommended a conversion tool in his response, which Earlz upvoted.  I have not used it myself, but two SO members are fans of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
XmlElement billingElem = (XmlElement)xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/order/billing");
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for your time.

Kanta